# Errors in Integral Estimate of Gaussian using Trapezoidal Rule

Tags: python, numerics, integration

I'm trying to estimate the percentage error in computing the integral of a Gaussian via composite trapezoidal rule versus via an exact formula. To do this I've generated a gaussian with mean 0, standard deviation $\sigma = 1$ and amplitude $A = 1$ in Python (plotted below), on a grid of $N$ points in the range $[-2\sigma,2\sigma]$, and used `scipy.integrate.trapz` to compute the approximate integral $A$ for a range of different $N$.

[image]

For the exact integral I used the formula $I = \int_{-x}^{x}e^{\frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2}} dt = \sqrt{2\pi}\sigma\text{erf}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}\sigma})$ to compute the exact integral between $\pm$ two standard deviations of the mean as $I = \int_{-2\sigma}^{2\sigma}e^{\frac{-t^2}{2\sigma^2}} dt = \sqrt{2\pi}\sigma\text{erf}(\sqrt{2})$, or

$I = \sqrt{2\pi}\text{erf}(\sqrt{2})$

in this $\sigma = 1$ case. The % error is then $E = \frac{|I - A|}{I}\cdot 100$. Below is a plot of $\frac{1}{E}$ versus $N$

[image]

and for reference a plot of $E$ verus $N$.

[image]

Now I would expect $E \propto \frac{1}{N^2}$ but this is not seen here. Would anyone be able to help me figure out why?

I've included my code below. Thank you in advance!

```
from scipy.integrate import trapz
from scipy.special import erf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

errs = np.array([]) # Errors in integral estimates
Ns = np.array([]) # Sample sizes tried

def get_percent_err(N, errs, Ns):
    A = 1 # Amplitude of Gaussian
    std = 1 # Standard deviation of Gaussian
    r = 2*std # Extent of domain
    dt = 2*r/N # Step
    t = np.linspace(-r,r,N) # Domain
    gauss = A*np.exp(-((t)**2)/(2*(std**2))) # Gaussian function
    
    actual_area = np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*A*std*erf(np.sqrt(2)) # Exact gaussian integral from -2*std to +2*std
    est_area = trapz(gauss, dx=dt) # Estimated integral via trapezium rule
    percent_err = (abs(actual_area - est_area)/actual_area)*100 # Percentage error
    
    errs = np.append(errs, percent_err)
    Ns = np.append(Ns, N)
    
    return errs, Ns

# Sweep through a range of sample sizes and obtain errors for each
min_samples = 100
max_samples = 100100
sample_step = 100
samples = np.arange(min_samples,max_samples,sample_step)

for N in samples:
    errs, Ns = get_percent_err(N, errs, Ns)

# Plot reciprocal of error in integral against sample size
plt.figure()
plt.plot(1/Ns,errs)
plt.xlabel("1 / Samples (1 / N)")
plt.ylabel("% Error in Integral (E)")
plt.title("Plot of % Error (E) in Integral versus 1 / Samples (1 / N)")
```

**UPDATE:**

For reasons that are unknown to me (though I believe it has something to do with numerical precision), this code, adapted from [this link](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Epwalls/math-python/integration/trapezoid-rule/), gives an expected result.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import erf
from scipy.integrate import trapz as trapz_scipy
from pandas import DataFrame

def trapz(f,a,b,N=50):
    x = np.linspace(a,b,N+1) # N+1 points make N subintervals
    y = f(x)
    dx = (b - a)/N
    T = trapz_scipy(y, dx=dx)
    return T

def get_err(N, errs):
    A = 1
    std = 1
    f = lambda x : A*np.exp(-x**2/(2*std**2))
    a = -2*std; b = 2*std;
    
    I = np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*A*std*erf(np.sqrt(2))
    T = trapz(f,a,b,N)
    return np.append(errs, 100*np.abs(I - T)/T)

min_samples = 10
max_samples = 1000
sample_step = 10
sample_sizes = np.arange(min_samples,max_samples+sample_step,sample_step)

errs = np.array([], dtype=np.float64)

for s in sample_sizes:
    errs = get_err(s, errs)
    
err_vs_sample_size = DataFrame({'% Error' : errs, 'Samples' : sample_sizes})

plt.figure()
plt.plot(1/sample_sizes**2,errs)
plt.xlabel("1 / Samples (1 / N)")
plt.ylabel("% Error in Integral (E)")
plt.title("Plot of % Error (E) in Integral versus 1 / Samples (1 / N)")
```

Error plot:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps your error is that you have only N-1 subintervals but your dt is set as if you had N subintervals

Comment: Not totally sure I understand what you are saying in the above, but is https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/sirev56-3_385.pdf of interest, especially around page 400?

Comment: It looks to me like a simple bug: in the second version, the one that works, linspace is called with N+1, which means there are N subintervals. But in the first version, that doesn’t work, linspace is called with N, which means there are N-1 subintervals. The subinterval size, dt, is assumed in both cases to be 2r/N, consistent only with the linspace in the second version.

Comment: Yep that turned out to be the problem, oops! Thanks guys!